# QT5 custom QWidget cannot be displayed

Tags: qt, qt5

I'm using QT to add four play Windows, each with a right-click menu,
I want the effect:
[Using the effects of the QWidget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYTzK.png)

code:

```
        m_layout->setSpacing(0);
        m_layout->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0);
        QWidget *w1= new QWidget(video_window);
        QWidget *w2= new QWidget(video_window);
        QWidget *w3= new QWidget(video_window);
        QWidget *w4= new QWidget(video_window);
        m_layout->addWidget(w1,0,0,1,1);
        m_layout->addWidget(w2,0,1,1,1);
        m_layout->addWidget(w3,1,0,1,1);
        m_layout->addWidget(w4,1,1,1,1);
        video_window->setLayout(m_layout);
```

But it doesn't show when I replace widget with my custom widget:

```
Video_play::Video_play(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    this->init();
}


void Video_play::init()
{
    Act_stop=new QAction(tr("停止预览"),this);
    Act_preview=new QAction(tr("预览"),this);

    Act_cut1=new QAction(tr("全屏"),this);
    Act_cut4=new QAction(tr("切换4画面"),this);
    Act_cut8=new QAction(tr("切换8画面"),this);
    Act_cut16=new QAction(tr("切换16画面"),this);

    connect(Act_stop, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(stop_preview()));
    connect(Act_preview, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(action_preview()));

    connect(Act_cut1, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(cut_1()));
    connect(Act_cut4, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(cut_4()));
    connect(Act_cut8, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(cut_8()));
    connect(Act_cut16, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(cut_16()));
    this->setStyleSheet("QMenu {background-color:rgba(255,255,255,1);border:1px solid rgba(82,130,164,1);}QMenu::item:selected {background:rgba(82,130,164,1);border:1px solid rgba(82,130,164,1);}");
 }
 void Video_play::contextMenuEvent(QContextMenuEvent *event)
 {

    QCursor cur=this->cursor();
    QMenu *menu=new QMenu(this);

    menu->addAction(Act_preview);
    menu->addAction(Act_stop);
    menu->addAction(Act_cut1);
    menu->addAction(Act_cut4);
    menu->addAction(Act_cut8);
    menu->addAction(Act_cut16);
    menu->exec(cur.pos());
}
```

but:

[Using the effects of the custom QWidget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlxzl.png)

Comment: Please, [edit] your question: 1.) title: _Qt5 custom Widgth_ "widget" or "width"? (I was uncertain.) 2.) Please, try to describe your problem in text. 3.) I embedded the images (prohibited to beginners for safety reasons) but both appeared equal to me and didn't help me to clarify your intention. (You might have been something mixed while uploading.) Side note: It would help to present a [mcve] using English exclusively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The custom Widget adds the following method to solve the problem

```
void CustomWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
 {
     QStyleOption opt;
     opt.init(this);
     QPainter p(this);
     style()->drawPrimitive(QStyle::PE_Widget, &opt, &p, this);
 }
```